# TFS 2012 only retrieves Existing File conflicts

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a problem using TFS in Visual Studio 2012 when I 'Get Latest Version'.  Whenever there are conflicts, all are of type 'Existing File', with the only options being to take the server version or the local version, with no merging operation possible, and this has only happened recently, but I'm not sure when.

From some of my reading on the subject this is caused by the files not being bound to source control.  I have done no editing of the files outside of Visual Studio itself.  These conflicts always seem to happen whenever the server has an updated version of the local version whether a change has been made locally or not.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, unless you have changed those files specifically, always take the server version and let it resolve the conflict naturally. Where I have seen this error occur happen most often is when running in an environment using gated builds, or doing a standard build including a shelf set and telling the build to check in if successful. What is happening is you have those files checked out locally with the same changes that the build server checked in. If you are using a gated build there is an option to preserve your chenges locally. Make sure that it is **not** set when you "Check In". I put that Check In in quotes, because in a gated build you dont actually check in, a shelf set is created with your changes and merged on top of the latest code on the build server.

Comment: It did end up being a shelved check-in that was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

My solution when it comes to this is simple: 
I right click on my branch, then I click on Advanced -> Get Specific Version

On type choose Last version, check the two checkboxes and click Get.

Hope it´s useful. Let me know if it works for you.